# Lemma To Proving wilson's Theorem

Tags: number-theory

I have come across the following question in my textbook stating that if $p$ is a prime and $x^2%=[a]^2$ that $x\equiv a$ mod(p) or $x \equiv -a\ $mod (p). After showing that if $a \equiv 0$ mod(p), then $x \equiv 0$ mod(p), now I am stuck for any other values. I know that 1 and -1 are self inverse in Z$_p$ but other than that I am lost. Thanks

Edit: I also know that each inverse is unique :)

Trying to show that $x\equiv a$ mod(p) or $x \equiv -a\ $mod (p) so that when I prove wilson's theorem than other than 1 and -1 (and 0) that pairs of unique elements in Zp (p prime) will be inverses.

Comment: @Weaam is that better?

Comment: Thanks. If $x^2 = 1 \mod p$. Then $p$ divides $x^2 - 1 = (x+1)(x-1)$, but since $p$ is prime, it divides either $x+1$ or $x-1$, but they must be $p$ or $0$, so $x$ must satisfy $x \equiv 1 \mod p$ or $x \equiv -1 \mod p$.

Comment: Exactly what I needed thanks.